# vector script in python 3

Tags: python, json, vector

I'm writing a code to calculate some vector-operations my scalarproduct script doesn't work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\A-PC\Desktop\Kopie von vektorrechnung.py", line 28, in <module>
    D = D + my_list1[i] * my_list2[i] #this part prints an Error-Code
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

The first block makes no problems, I think the problem is the json call. I don't understand, why the first block works an the second one fails. Is mupliplication not defined on lists created by json ?

here is my code:

```
import json

str_list1 = input("Geben Sie den 1. Vektor in der Form [x, y, z] ein: ") #enter 3 coordinates
my_list1 = json.loads(str_list1) #build vector as list in R3
print(my_list1)

str_list2 = input("Geben Sie den 2. Vektor in der Form [x, y, z] ein: ")# ""
my_list2 = json.loads(str_list2) #""
print(my_list2)

print("Welche Berechnung möchten Sie ausführen ?") #choose case
print ("[v]ektoraddition") #vector addition
print ("[s]kalarprodukt") #scalarproduct
Fall = input() # input first char

if Fall == "v": #when input = "v"
    C=[]

    for i in range(3):
         C+=[my_list1[i] + my_list2[i]]
print("Das Ergebnis lautet: ")
print(C) #this part works

elif Fall == "s": #when input = "s"
D=[]

    for i in range(3):
        D = D + my_list1[i] * my_list2[i] #this part prints an Error-Code

print("Das Skalarprodukt beträgt: ")
print(D) 
else:
    print("Ungültiger Eingabewert")
```

Comment: Consider the difference between `C+=[my_list1[i] + my_list2[i]]` (which does addition of two lists) and `D = D + my_list1[i] * my_list2[i]`, with no `[]` around the result of the multiplication, which does addition of a list and the result of the multiplication. You probably mean `D = 0` instead of `D = []` in the earlier line.

Comment: yes that's it empty scalar not empty vector thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is, as the error says, you are trying to concatenate a list with an int. Only a list can be concatenated with another list. If you want to add elements, then you would need to use `.append(..)` function

```
for i in range(3):
    D.append(my_list1[i] * my_list2[i])

print(D)
```

From your code, I can make out that you are trying to do a dot product between two lists. In that case you can do `sum(D)` as above, or as @Steve says in the comment, do something like below:

```
D = 0
for i in range(3):
    D += my_list1[i] * my_list2[i]

print D
```